# Indenting code within .R script without using a function

Tags: r, rstudio, auto-indent, code-folding

I am new to R, and despite searching the forums I have been unable to find a solution to indenting code within both the Source window and Document Outline (`Ctrl+Shift+O`).

An example is shown below.

[image: img1]

Ideally, I would want the code to function as below when pressing `Alt+O`

[image: img2]

This function does seem to be implemented in some fashion as you get the indented code with functions but this is less than ideal.

```
    # Section 1 ----------------------------------------------------------- 
    function(x) {
    # Section 1A  ===========================================================
    }
```

Has anyone found a work-around to implement this?

Comment: interesting. I didn't even know that the document outline existed :D I don't see a way that this is possible - I think the outline is also more specifically for functions, if you have several levels, and to keep an overview about those. A workaround is to add two characters, e.g. underscores before your sub-levels, i.e. `# __Section 1A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Foztarz I posted this as an issue about a year ago on the GitHub. They claimed it was a worthy enhancement but they keep pushing it to the next version of RStudio lol. My work-around was similar. I used Alt codes to insert symbols I found a bit more visually appealing over `.`

```
 # ▬ Section A ------


    # ▐ ▬ Section A.1-----------
```

Here's what it looks like inside RStudio

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, this sort of nested indent is implemented for Markdown sections (for e.g. R Markdown documents), e.g.

[image: outline]

However, this sort of nested is not implemented for sections in plain R scripts. You might consider filing this as a [feature request](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues) for the RStudio team.

Comment: This was a great suggestion. I posted it as a feature request. If anyone falls onto this question and would like to see this added, you can go +1 the feature [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4124)

Answer (score 2):

Not a fix but a workaround:

Any whitespace after a "." is included in the heading, so a "." followed by a tab or space can be used to create indented headers preceded by a ".".

```
# Section title ---------------------------------------------------------------

# . Subsection A --------------------------------------------------------------

# . . A.1 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Would still be nice to see this implemented the way it is in R markdown, but in the mean time might make it easier to navigate scripts using sub-headers.

[Screenshot of example script using dot-tab to indent headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnPXr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Two additions:

1. [Box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) look much better than the characters mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63812437/13776976 [@Patricks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63812437/13776976)
2. From RStudio 1.4 on, you can indicate sub-sections by additional '#' at the start of the line, see [RStudio How To Article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections)